# UnsignedInt operations in Java

Tags: java, unsigned-integer

I think it is clear but for sure I have decided to ask.

If I have something like this.

```
int secs=2power32-1 //Unsigned int read from file as Java sign. int.
if(Integer.compareUnsigned(secs,3600)>=0){ //Get hours from secs.
start[0]=Integer.divideUnsigned(secs,3600);
secs=secs-start[0]*3600;
}

if(Integer.compareUnsigned(secs,60)>=0){ // Get min. from secs.
 ...
}
```

I am not 100% sure that the second comparison compute with correct number (secs).

Please does anybody know a proof?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `int secs=2e32` won't compile

Comment: I am really sorry for mistake. It is already corrected.

Comment: All of this looks good except for `secs`, which should just be -1.

Comment: @Uživatel Where is `int secs=2power32-1` valid Java?

Comment: When you parse unsigned int from File you can get signed represenation of unsigned int it this value or if you initiate int as -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `secs = secs-start[0]*3600` does what you expect.

The reason why Integer doesn't have unsigned method add, subtract, and multiply methods is that they are exactly the same (bit-for-bit) as the signed operations.  If you do 65535*65537, for example, you get -1.  Interpreted as an unsigned int, those bits make 2^31-1 as you would expect.

This was a pretty important property in the early days of computers, because it meant the computer didn't need to have separate instructions and logic for signed vs. unsigned operations.

For proof, you really just need to understand that those operations (* + -) on integers all work mod 2^32.  When you interpret a negative int as an unsigned value, the unsigned value you assign to it equals the signed value + 2^32.  The value mod 2^32 is exactly the same.

Comment: Okey, I understood. It is just matter of represantion of normal int range. The operation are always done on normal binary numbers so the resulting number depends on signed numbers conception. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

One way to test the computation is to convert the original `unsigned int` to an equivalent `long`, and perform the computation with the regular operators :

```
String bin = Integer.toBinaryString (-1); // -1 is the int number having the highest
                                          // value as unsigned int - (2^32-1)
long secsl = Long.parseLong (bin, 2); // will result in 4294967295
if(secsl >=3600){ //Get hours from secs.
  long temp = secsl / 3600;
  secsl=secsl-temp*3600;
}

if(secsl >= 60){ // Get min. from secs.
  ...
}
```

`secsl` should have the same value as the unsigned value of `secs` in your code snippet (which you can view by calling `Integer.toUnsignedString(secs)`.

P.S.

In both snippets (yours and mine) the second condition is true, since `secsl` and `secs` are both `1695`. Therefore your computation is correct.

Comment: Thank you for verification. It was helpful. I was thinking about binary operation proof but it is no matter now. I hava found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for sure it can be used this:

```
secs=Integer.remainderUnsigned(secs,3600);
```

But as said Eran the result is always *secs=1695* no matter if normal difference is used to compute the remainder on unsigned number represented as signed one or it is computed by unsigned remainder.

**If onebody knows the bitwise proof I would be glad to see it.**